# I need a formula or VBA to hightlight all duplicate numbers across 3 columns except the first instance of each number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I need a formula or VBA to highlight the duplicate numbers after the first instance of that number in the columns (E,S & T).  Have attempted to use other IF formulas which have not worked.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you share what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Use conditional formatting by formula like `COUNTIF(from A1 till current cell) > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

> highlight the duplicate numbers after the first instance of that number in the columns (E,S & T)

I'm assuming this means to highlight all values that occur more than once *except the first occurance*, counted separately for each column. Which means for the screenshot your post contains, none of the values will be highlighted (because while there are multiple instances of the same value, the duplicates aren't within the same column).

Add conditional formatting for matching a formula, then input this:
`=(ROW() - MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())), search_range, 0)) > 1`

where `search_range` must be substituted for the relevant range. This means you will need three instances of this CF, one for column E (for instance: `search_range` subs to `$E$2:$E$8`), one for column S and one for column T. Adapt the ranges as necessary. The number `1` at the end of the formula also needs to be set to whatever row your data starts at in the respective column - I go into a bit of detail about this towards the end.

This is what the formula does:

- Find the current row number
- Look for the value of the current row
- If the row number minus the matched row is 1 or less, we've matched "ourself" - which means the current value is the first instance of itself and should **not** be highlighted
- If the row number minus the matched row is above 1, we've matched with a number higher up in the list - which means the current value is not the first instance of itself and should be highlighted

This is possible because the `MATCH` function halts at the *first* result.

One more thing to note is that the result returned from `MATCH` is local to the matrix you search within, so if your `search_range` is `A10:A20` for example, a value located in `A10` will by `MATCH` be returned as `1` (because it is the first row in the specified range). This means that if the range you sub for `search_range` starts in row 2 or lower, you will have to modify the `1` at the end of this formula. The number you should input there is the same as the row number where your data starts.

Here's how it will look:

[image]

Comment: With regards to the 3 columns, the 'E' Column will be 'to be worked' for that day, while columns S & T can change (Incoming calls and Incoming Emails.  Therefore the formula will need to cross reference all 3 columns with each other (where possible).  For Example,  Client 133 might have actions required for their daily listing, but then they might call or email as well.  I need the formula to count that it was worked originally, and then highlight that they have made contact again if I list their number in column S again. (Column E should never have duplicate values) Hope this helps to clarify

Comment: Which columns should count against the duplicate count? Does `E` factor into this comparison at all?

Comment: Columns S & T should be able to have duplicates of Column E.

Comment: Well in that case, the answer is easily adaptable - simply set `search_range` to the relevant portion of `E`-column, and apply the conditional formatting only to columns `S` and `T`.

Comment: Ok.  Have gone back in and when entering the formula "=(ROW() - MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()), search_range, 0)) > 1" (attempted both in the spreadsheet itself and in conditional formatting) it comes up with "You've entered too many arguments for this function.

Comment: To clarify further, column E will list any Loans that require actioning or attention for that day, (This column will never have a duplicated number in this same column - all loan numbers would be listed only once in this column).  However, if a client was then to call or email us, we then have to list the loan number in the respective column (S or T).  I need the formula to search the three columns and highlight all instances (bar the first instance) of any loan number.

Comment: Therefore using the original screenshot as an example, The loans in E have been worked, and loan 139, 134 & 133 have all called back & 137, 133 & 136 have emailed, these should be highlighted as duplicates.   So, If I was to receive a call from Loan 146 and then a call, have loan 146 listed under email column (T) as the original and then when listed under the Call column (S) highlighted as the duplicate.  Hope this helps.   Where possible, If I can get an exact formula, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't input `search_range`, as I've already said. You have to enter the actual range.

Comment: Even when entering the range, I have these issues.

Comment: So, Even when trying to use the below

"=(ROW() - MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()), E2:E15, 0)) > 1"

I get the same errors.

Comment: There was a `)` missing. I've corrected this part of my answer. You should qualify the range in absolutes, and you also need to modify the final number in accordance with what row your data starts on. Your formula should be like this: `=(ROW() - MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())), $E$2:$E$15, 0)) > 2`